# How to extract and save images from tensorboard event summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Given a tensorflow event file, how can I extract images corresponding to a specific tag, and then save them to disk in a common format e.g. `.png`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could extract the images like so. The output format may depend on how the image is encoded in the summary, so the resulting write to disk may need to use another format besides `.png`

```
import os
import scipy.misc
import tensorflow as tf

def save_images_from_event(fn, tag, output_dir='./'):
    assert(os.path.isdir(output_dir))

    image_str = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
    im_tf = tf.image.decode_image(image_str)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    with sess.as_default():
        count = 0
        for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(fn):
            for v in e.summary.value:
                if v.tag == tag:
                    im = im_tf.eval({image_str: v.image.encoded_image_string})
                    output_fn = os.path.realpath('{}/image_{:05d}.png'.format(output_dir, count))
                    print("Saving '{}'".format(output_fn))
                    scipy.misc.imsave(output_fn, im)
                    count += 1
```

And then an example invocation may look like:

`save_images_from_event('path/to/event/file', 'tag0')`

Note that this assumes the event file is fully written -- in the case that it's not, some error handling is probably necessary.

Comment: Nice code, though it will work way better if you replace the last condition with "if v.tag.find(tag) !=-1:". this one helped me;)

Comment: @Eisa that will match tag strings with substrings, which user may not want (it depends). if small substrings of tags uniquely identify tags, your approach will work. can you elaborate on what you mean by "work way better"? glad it helped you

Comment: for my case, I had some 'output/image/#', 'input/image/#', 'shear/image/#' ..., (# = 0, 1, ...)
The tag names where output, input, shear, .. but your code could not extract the images until I modified it as I described.

Comment: What are tags? what is event file? Please give a concrete example

Answer (score 11):

For those who can also do without code, there is an elegant way in the Tensorboard UI.

1. In the upper left corner, select the checkbox `Show data download links`
2. In the lower left corner, select the download icon which lets you download a svg file.
3. In the lower right corner, select data download links for the raw data, handy for those who want to do more sophisticated data analysis or data visualization

[image]

Comment: This answer is not what the author wanted. The question is how to download the images in the Image section, not the plot from the Scalars section.

Comment: @koha That download button now can "Download Current Chart as SVG". tf/tfboard 2.5

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TensorFlow 2, this works nicely

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from typing import List
import tensorflow as tf


TensorBoardImage = namedtuple("TensorBoardImage", ["topic", "image", "cnt"])


def extract_images_from_event(event_filename: str, image_tags: List[str]):
    topic_counter = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    serialized_examples = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(event_filename)
    for serialized_example in serialized_examples:
        event = event_pb2.Event.FromString(serialized_example.numpy())
        for v in event.summary.value:
            if v.tag in image_tags:

                if v.HasField('tensor'):  # event for images using tensor field
                    s = v.tensor.string_val[2]  # first elements are W and H

                    tf_img = tf.image.decode_image(s)  # [H, W, C]
                    np_img = tf_img.numpy()

                    topic_counter[v.tag] += 1

                    cnt = topic_counter[v.tag]
                    tbi = TensorBoardImage(topic=v.tag, image=np_img, cnt=cnt)

                    yield tbi
```

Although, 'v' has an image field, it is empty.

I used

```
    tf.summary.image("topic", img)
```

to add the images to the event file.

Comment: Please include usage example. Also `NameError: name 'event_pb2' is not defined`

Comment: from tensorflow.core.util import event_pb2