# Tensorboard extract scalar by a script

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to extract my scalars by a script, because I have a lot of test runs.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232779/how-to-extract-and-save-images-from-tensorboard-event-summary) I can get all tf summaries of one board. I can even separate the tag for the loss:

```
<class 'tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2.Value'>
tag: "training_loss"
simple_value: 0.0590251199901104
```

But it seems that every loss value that is saved as on `summary_pb2.Value`. I could extract every loss single value, but I don't find an information about the step number or time of these single values, so that I can order them (They have the same tag as well). Unfortunately this is not well documented, does someone know how I can get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `EventAccumulator`:
You can pass the model directory to the `_load_run()` function.

```
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator
import numpy as np

def _load_run(path):
  event_acc = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(path)
  event_acc.Reload()
  data = {}

  for tag in sorted(event_acc.Tags()["scalars"]):
    x, y = [], []

    for scalar_event in event_acc.Scalars(tag):
      x.append(scalar_event.step)
      y.append(scalar_event.value)

    data[tag] = (np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y))
  return data

print(_load_run("/models/vae/run_1"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you!